# Stored Procedure statement terminated Error?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, insert, null, sql-server-2014

I am using below stored procedure to insert records from another view:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPemployeeinsert]
    (@date DATETIME)
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @idinsert AS INT 

    SELECT @idinsert = MAX (ID) + 1 
    FROM dbo.EMP

    INSERT INTO [SRV-RVS].dbo.emp (LASTNAME, ID)
        SELECT 
            [FirstName], 
            @idinsert + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [FirstName]) - 1
        FROM 
            drv-rds2014.[HumanResources].[testEmployeeView]
        WHERE 
            ModifiedDate = @date 

    INSERT INTO [SRV-RVS].dbo.empldf(CIVILID, JOBTITLE, ISSUEDATE, ID)
        SELECT
            [PhoneNumber], [JobTitle], [ModifiedDate], 
            @idinsert + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [FirstName]) - 1
        FROM 
            drv-rds2014.[HumanResources].[testEmployeeView]
        WHERE  
            ModifiedDate = @date
END
```

While executing the stored procedure I am getting this error:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure SPemployeeinsert, Line 42
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'SRV-RVS.dbo.EMP'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>
> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure SPemployeeinsert, Line 48
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'SRV-RVS.dbo.EMPLDF'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I am trying to pass date like '01/04/2009;'  which will copy from the source and insert into the destination using this stored procedure.

Regards

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3IZE.jpg)

[Stored procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsUXw.png)

Comment: the message is pretty clear: `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID'`.

Comment: Why in your first query you use where ID= @idinsert ?

Comment: @jens . my declare statement needs to insert the maximum value from the ID column and use for the insert statement ..here its returning the error

Comment: @etsa . I am trying to create variable which will store the ID and pass it two insert statement

Comment: As Jens said in his answer I think too that WHERE ID=@idinsert  seems not correct

Comment: @etsa ...Now stored procedure is returing duplicate value error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with your procedure. First:

```
DECLARE @idinsert as int
select @idinsert= MAX (ID)+1 from dbo.EMP
where ID= @idinsert
```

Variable `@idinsert` is not initialized, so its value is `NULL`. You need to change this to:

```
DECLARE @idinsert as int
select @idinsert= MAX(ID)+1 from dbo.EMP
```

Second problem - for `@date` it is possible, that your view `drv-rds2014. [HumanResources].[testEmployeeView]` will return multiple values and insert queries will fail cause of duplicate values in column `Id`. You need to change your insert statements to:

```
INSERT [SRV-RVS].dbo.emp (LASTNAME,ID)
  SELECT [FirstName],@idinsert + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [FirstName]) - 1
  FROM drv-rds2014. [HumanResources].[testEmployeeView]
  WHERE ModifiedDate=@date 

  insert [SRV-RVS].dbo.empldf
  (CIVILID,JOBTITLE,ISSUEDATE,ID)
  select [PhoneNumber],[JobTitle],[ModifiedDate],@idinsert + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [FirstName]) - 1
  FROM drv-rds2014. [HumanResources].[testEmployeeView]
  WHERE  ModifiedDate=@date
```

Comment: @aryan In comments above you wrote that you have problem `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'select (convert(int),MAX (ID)+1 from dbo.EMP)' to data type int.`, but I can't see `select (convert(int),MAX (ID)+1 from dbo.EMP)` in your code... I can't help you if you don't write your ACTUAL code...

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'MAX (ID)+1 from dbo.EMP)' to data type int. , this is the error i am returing  after the changes you told me to make

Comment: `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'select (convert(int),MAX (ID)+1 from dbo.EMP)' to data type int.` ,  this happend when  i added a select statment infront of declare statement. sorry for the confusion

Comment: @aryan I didn't write anywhere `'select (convert(int),MAX (ID)+1 from dbo.EMP)'`, so it is your own code.

Comment: `set@idinsert= select MAX(ID)+1 from dbo.EMP ` .  i tried this. thats how i returned the above error. sorry for the confusion there

Comment: @aryan If you want to use `SET`, you need to write `set @idinsert= (select MAX(ID)+1 from dbo.EMP)`, but it is still not my code...

Comment: i tried your code but its  returing `.` ` Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'MAX (ID)+1 from dbo.EMP)' to data type int`

Comment: @aryan I am sorry, but I can't believe it... Could you add screenshot with your query?

Comment: @aryan I want to see you procedure, not how you are executing this.

Comment: @aryan Mate, Remove apostrophies and last `)`. It shoould be `SELECT @idinsert = MAX(Id) + 1 FROM dbo.EMP` BUT WITHOUT ANY APOSTROPHIES!

Comment: its fine now ..  I can update the table now.. thanks Rokuto  for staying this long

Comment: also, i  didint get this part of your change..  `+ ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [FirstName]) - 1`

Comment: @aryan I am on phone and I can't link you site, but you can Google function Row_Number and read about it. This function returns position of each row in specific order (in this query rows are ordered by first name), -1 is needed to not create gaps on Id column.

Comment: i am familiar with row numbers and ranking functions,  but this use-case is something i couldn't get it ..

Comment: @aryan Hey, here: http://rextester.com/TYPT21417 is simple query with using `ROW_NUMBER` which should help you to understand why used it in your procedure.

Comment: so,it's actually subtracting from the row number directly  . could you  tell something about  `to not to create gaps on ID column`. Even I can insert without that part but what this gap really mean here  .

Comment: @aryan. If you don't substract 1 from `ROW_NUMBER` you will get gaps in Id column, it means that there will be row with id, e.g. 100, but not with 101, because `@idinsert` will be equal 101 (you are adding 1 to maximal id in table `dbo.EMP`), and `ROW_NUMBER` will be always greater than 1.

Comment: i   read your  post around five times to understood what it really meant ..

Answer (score 0):

```
select @idinsert= MAX (ID)+1 from dbo.EMP
    where ID= @idinsert
```

Returns `null`. remove the `where` clause

Comment: @aryan Remove whole `where ID= @idinsert `.

Comment: Something else is going now,  I am getting duplicate value errror , its not incrementing the ID from the column. only trying to use the  last ID and using for the insert

Comment: @aryan You are inserting into 2 different tables. Are you sure, that maximum Id in table `[SRV-RVS].dbo.empldf` is equal to maximum Id in table `[SRV-RVS].dbo.emp`? Which table gives you duplicate value error?

Comment: yes , last ID is same for both tables. I tried to  set a fixed value to idinsert and tried , like DECLARE @idinsert as int
 set @idinsert=194908  , but it return the same error

Comment: @aryan Database is not a version of your DBMS. :) I want to know, to which database you are actually connected. Try `select MAX (ID) from [SRV-RVS].dbo.EMP` and tell us what is the output.

Comment: @Rokuto its returing the output 194907

Comment: @aryan Ok, so what is returning query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM drv-rds2014.[HumanResources].[testEmployeeView]
  WHERE ModifiedDate = '01/04/2009'`?

Comment: three records were inserting for the query .

Comment: @aryan And this is a problem. You are trying to insert three records with the same Id...

Comment: @Rokuto But that is  not the Problem, as you can see in the error message `Cannot insert the value NULL `

Comment: @Jens It is, he changed query (removed `where ID= @idinsert` as you suggested) and he gets another problem with duplicate values.

Comment: @rokuto .. If, how can i increment ID for  each record

Comment: @aryan Use `SELECT your_columns, @idinsert + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 FROM ...` or do it as Gagan suggested.

Comment: Identity column is not possible for this particular table  @Rokuto

Comment: @aryan so use `SELECT your_columns, @idinsert + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 FROM ...` ... If you need order replace `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` with `ORDER BY [FirstName]`.

Comment: Conversion f.ailed when converting the varchar value 'MAX (ID)+1 from dbo.EMP' to data type int .. even changing the datatype doesnt work for me
@Rokuto

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when you try to insert null data on the columns where null value is not allowed.
In your query id can not be null when your inserting data in both tables. You can insert ID or make id as identity.

Comment: Declare part is  inserting an ID  using    DECLARE @idinsert as int
    select @idinsert= MAX (ID)+1 from dbo.EMP

Comment: Remove where clause from declare query.

Comment: it's removed but now there is an issue with duplicate ID.  here,  I am trying to insert multiple records and my ID should increment for  each entry . it's not happening

Comment: Is it possible for you to make ID column Identity?

Comment: its not possible for this column .